# What is wrong with my .click() event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-click-event

My problem is the .click event below. The `'nav'` and `'#closemenu'` div hide as expected on document ready, but the click event won't work to save my life. Either I'm missing something embarrassingly small (which I hope is unlikely because I copy/pasted the code from the jQuery API page and then changed only the ID and alert) or else I have no idea what my issue is. Any help is much appreciated.

Here's my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('nav').hide();
  $('#closemenu').hide();

  $('#menuicon').click(function() {
    alert('Hello, test');
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Page Title Here</h1>
    <div id="menuicon">
      <img src="mobile_menu.png">
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <a href="">
          <li class="upCase">Projects</li>
        </a>
        <a href="">
          <li clas s="upCase">Profile</li>
        </a>
        <a href="">
          <li class="upCase">Contact</li>
        </a>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="closemenu">
      <p>X</p>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: Pop open your console, any errors? (F12 on most browsers - or options, dev tools, JS Console)

Comment: works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/e8k2eboj/  you have your html tag right?

Comment: seems to work on jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/342/. must be something with referencing of files

Comment: Works for me too, on SO snippet.

Comment: my guess is an unreported js error or missing js include ? but you say no errors?

Comment: What browser are you using? The code is all fine and should work. I'm fact, it works (see jsfiddle by @indubitablee).

Comment: @Jonathan.Brink Definitely...I was just truncating...there's more code in my body as well. Is my jQuery call bad/old? I can't figure out why the hide functions would work and the alert wouldn't...

Comment: @PeterScott Correct, no errors at all.

Comment: @PhilM. Chrome. I agree, the code _seems_ right...it's maddening.

Comment: Is that the extent of your app.js file, or did you omit any code from it?

Comment: If you have more code share all of it. There's probably something more minor going on

Comment: @Stryner that is the full extent of my app.js file.

Comment: @PhilM. that is the full extent of my app.js file.

Comment: What does `console.log($("*#menuicon").length);` show? (note the `*`)

Comment: Is this really your entire html code? Else I believe you have multiple divs with the menuicon id..

Comment: @PhilM. Yes, it is...I cut everything out just to work on this. I only have 1 menuicon ID.

Comment: Is the menuicon div getting dynamically loaded into your body? Somehow your DOM does not recognize this specific div.

Comment: @PhilM. No, it's hardcoded in...very odd/frustrating. There's no way the behavior is being cached is there? That feels like a dumb question to even ask...

Comment: Caching is possible, but doesn't get the results you get. If you are in doubt, Chrome has SHIFT +R to remove the cache and reload the page.

Comment: @PhilM. well, not that either...I'll keep poking around. It must be a small error I just haven't caught yet.

Comment: Why don't you just add the event directly like this <div id="menuicon" onclick="function name ()">

Comment: @DeepakRajappan I suppose I could...but that sort of defeats the whole purpose of having an external scripts. Not to mention I'm not sure how it would work, given that the function then applies to several child/parent elements unrelated to the #menuicon element.

Comment: If that's the case try this  $( "#menuicon" ).bind({ click: function() { alert (); });

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just add the event directly like this

For multiple div use the below

$( "#menuicon" ).bind({ click: function(){ alert ();}
 });